# How to fix the error incompatible angular ivy in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]
[image]
How to fix the error in module.ts here's my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^11.4.2",}
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.14",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^5.2.3",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"}
```

already update the angular/cli to 11.2.14. also the imports already update and restart the vscode and reinstall the node_module. still getting the error.